# What is the proper way to split a string by regex

Tags: c#

I have a text string with a custom macro:

> "Some text **{MACRO(parameter1)}** more text **{MACRO(parameter2)}**"

In order to process the macro I want to split the string like that:

> #### expected result
>
> "Some text "
>   "{MACRO(parameter1)}"
>   " more text "
>   "{MACRO(parameter2)}"

I've tried to split the string using `Regex.Split()`

```
public static string[] Split(string input)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"{MACRO\((.*)\)}");
    var lines = regex.Split(input)
    return lines;
}
```

However Regex.Split() deletes the match itself and gives me the following:

> #### actual result
>
> "Some text "
>   " more text "

I know I could parse the string doing iterations of `.Match()` and `.Substring()`

But is there an easy way get the result along with the matches?

Comment: Your pattern does not work for me. It should be `@"{MACRO\([^})]*\)}"`. This will split the string correctly. Now if you also make the parameter part of the pattern (`[^})]`) a capture group (i.e. the full pattern should be `@"{MACRO\(([^})]*)\)}"`) then your function will work as expected.

Comment: Try this `regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"({MACRO\(.*?\)})");`

Comment: See this working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bClOo5

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride yeah the regex in the example is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string input = "Some text {MACRO(parameter1)} more text {MACRO(parameter2)}";
            string pattern = @"(?'text'[^\{]+)\{(?'macro'[^\}]+)\}";
            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("text : '{0}'; macro : '{1}'", match.Groups["text"].Value.Trim(), match.Groups["macro"].Value.Trim());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: No need to resort to `Regex.Matches()`. `Regex.Split()` does just fine when a capture group is used.

Comment: Good Night Nerd Pride : Xplit() returns a string[].  With my code I'm separating the text and macro into two groups so split will not work.